# Is there a way to allow the "Content Search web part" to show items from on-premises and sharepoint online sites which are based on the same AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-on-prem, content-search-web-part

i have the below Content Search web part, which is showing discussion board list items from all our on-premises sites, here is the content search web part settings, where i am defining the on-premises root site url to show items from all our sites:-
[image]

and then i define a refiner to only show discussion board items:-
[image]

now i will be migrating the root site to sharepoint online,while will leave the other sites inside the on-premises server. and this root site has a discussion board list item, **so can i modify my content search web part to show items from the migrated site as well as items from the on-premises sites?**
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Cloud (Hybrid) Search Service Application?

Comment: @TrevorSeward no i did not set anything regarding this..

Comment: That will be your first step before you can combine results. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/learn-about-cloud-hybrid-search-for-sharepoint